# How to swap out (update) toolchain to build native ROS

Tags: android, android-ndk, cmake, ros, catkin

I'm trying to build a native (Indigo) ROS package for Android with gcc 4.9. I was following the steps in this [link](http://wiki.ros.org/android_ndk/Tutorials/BuildingNativeROSPackages) (which use gcc 4.6).

So I changed gcc_version=4.9 in config.sh. Then got a message to set CMake variable ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN_NAME to one of the listed toolchains. But arm-linux-androideabi-4.9 was not listed (I think because Dockerfile seems to install Android NDK r8e? which may not include it?), however, I do have arm-linux-androideabi-4.9 included in an external (outside of the ROS tree) NDK (crystax). I then tried removing the Android NDK install section in the Dockerfile and have ANDROID_NDK set to my external NDK, but to no avail.

Am I missing a more obvious way to swap out the toolchain and build for Android?

Update:

I've commented out these (wget and tar) lines from the Dockerfile and set ANDROID_NDK to my Crystax NDK in my shell (also tried within Dockerfile) hoping this would change it, but so far this has been a no go.

roscpp_android/docker/Dockerfile ...

```
# Install Android NDK
# I commented these two RUN lines outs
# RUN wget http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r8e-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
# RUN tar -jxvf android-ndk-r8e-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2 -C /opt

# Set-up environment
# ENV ANDROID_NDK /opt/android-ndk-r8e
ENV ANDROID_NDK /home/me/tools/crystax-ndk-10.3.2
```

Comment: I'm betting the path to the NDK directory is stored in a variable somewhere. Right now it points to the older version of the NDK. I would grep for 'ndk' in the configuration files to see if I could find this path and modify it.

Comment: My understanding is that ANDROID_NDK is the var you're talking about. I've made an update to better show.

Comment: As the question is tagged with [cmake]: Have you deleted the CMakeCache.txt or better the complete build directory?

Comment: I've been removing the output directory which seems to be where all that is kept, but right not it looks like the problem is that it doesn't find the correct toolchain.